# Issue with backstretch code (DIV background)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-backstretch

I'm using [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) for fullscreen background.
On one of my website it works perfectly fine with this code just after the opening body tag:

```
<script>
$.backstretch([
      "images/1.jpg"
    , "images/2.jpg"
    , "images/3.jpg"
  ], {duration: 6000, fade: 750});

</script>
```

However on my new website (one page layout with several divs) that does not work. I tried the code below as suggested on backstretch website - I'd like a different full screen background per DIV:

```
<script>
 $("#presentation").backstretch("../images/bg-24.jpg");
 $("#presentation2").backstretch("../images/bg-25.jpg");
 $("#presentation3").backstretch("../images/bg-26.jpg");
</script>
```

then

```
<div id="presentation">
blablabla
</div>
```

blablabla
    


    blablabla

CSS Code:

```
#presentation {
    height: 1300px;

}

#presentation2 {
    height: 1300px;

}

#presentation3 {
    height: 1300px;

}
```

Comment: keep the `sript` tag after the `div` tag. You must call the DOM after HTML is completely loaded. and also please explain what do you mean by "_does not work_"? Can you see any error in developer tool of your browser?

Comment: you ARE calling `backstretch` in the `ready` arent you ?

Comment: Yes I'm calling backstretch

Comment: @ Mr Green - How can I check this 5using safari latest on mac) - tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Move script below the div tag
2. change it to following

   ```
   <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $.backstretch([
         "images/1.jpg"
       , "images/2.jpg"
        , "images/3.jpg"
      ], {duration: 6000, fade: 750});
   });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this code is the one using the "body" tag, in my case I want full screen background to be applicable to my DIVs. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Find this code inside jquery.backstretch.min.js
`return a("body").backstretch(c,b).data("backstretch")`

and change "body" to ".backstretch"

Now, give `.backstretch` class to your div

Done.